# How to add exception to .htaccess https-address conversion?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to convert URL from `http://` to `https://` in my site.

**How's possible to add an exception to .htaccess-file not to convert path when accessing specific folder?
For eg "/nohttps/" -folder**

---

what I want to happen:

```
http://example.com            --> https://example.com
http://example.com/something/ --> https://example.com/shomething/
http://example.com/nohttps/   --> http://example.com/nohttps/         ("no rewrite")
```

---

.htaccess file now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add second condition using `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nohttps
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: does not work...
"404 error".. tries to access "https://www.example.com/nohttps/index.html.var"

Comment: @user2748705 Ok try now. Remember this will only work with direct `http://` access

Comment: Tried with address
"http://example.com/nohttps/"
and tries to access
"https://example.com/nohttps/index.html.var"

Comment: @user2748705 So whats the issue? The above rule is still redirecting you to `https:` containing `nohttps` in url?